# How to give a constant and a dynamic argument to functions which are stored in an array

Tags: python, arrays

I use an array for storage of functions which needs to be called in a row:

```
def do_xslt(xsl, xml):
    newxml = dosomethingwithit(xsl,xml)
    return newxml

TRANSFORM_PIPELINE = [
    do_xslt('pass1.xsl'),
    do_xslt('pass2.xsl'),
    do_xslt('pass3.xsl'),
]
```

what I now want to do is to call the `TRANSFORM_PIPELINE` with its given argument and a dynamic one.

I have something like this in my mind which should call in a loop `do_xslt('passX.xsl', xml)`

```
for transform in TRANSFORM_PIPELINE:
    xml = transform(xml)
```

This approach is of course wrong. But how to make the right way in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to *partially apply* the function:

```
from functools import partial
TRANSFORM_PIPELINE = [
    partial(do_xslt, 'pass1.xsl'),
    partial(do_xslt, 'pass2.xsl'),
    partial(do_xslt, 'pass3.xsl')
]
```

Calling the functions returned by `partial()` will call `do_xslt('pass1.xsl', *args, **kwargs)` with `*args` and `**kwargs` being the arguments passed to the new function.

Demo:

```
>>> def do_xslt(xsl, xml):
...     print 'do_xslt(%r, %r)' % (xsl, xml)
...     return xml + '*' + xsl
...
>>> from functools import partial
>>> TRANSFORM_PIPELINE = [
...     partial(do_xslt, 'pass1.xsl'),
...     partial(do_xslt, 'pass2.xsl'),
...     partial(do_xslt, 'pass3.xsl')
... ]
>>> x = 'xml is lame'
>>> for transform in TRANSFORM_PIPELINE:
...     x = transform(x)
...     print x
...
do_xslt('pass1.xsl', 'xml is lame')
xml is lame*pass1.xsl
do_xslt('pass2.xsl', 'xml is lame*pass1.xsl')
xml is lame*pass1.xsl*pass2.xsl
do_xslt('pass3.xsl', 'xml is lame*pass1.xsl*pass2.xsl')
xml is lame*pass1.xsl*pass2.xsl*pass3.xsl
```

Comment: The example doesn't, but a real function would return the transformed argument. Anyway, I've updated it.

Comment: thanks. The partial function works. It's the best solution because I also have functions in TRANSFORM_PIPELINE which do not need a given constant (before doing xslt transform). So I can use partial everytime I need it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `functools.partial()` - http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial

```
TRANSFORM_PIPELINE = [
    functools.partial(do_xslt, 'pass1.xsl'),
    functools.partial(do_xslt, 'pass2.xsl'),
    functools.partial(do_xslt, 'pass3.xsl'),
]
```

Alternatively, you can also use a closure like so:

```
def do_xslt(xsl):
    def inner(xml):
        newxml = dosomethingwithit(xsl,xml)
        return newxml
    return inner
```

This way, you can keep the TRANSFORM_PIPELINE exactly the way you have it now.